# Conditional removing of text using sed

Tags: linux, sed, replace

I have this file:

```
HEADER2023053112460600000004000000000.000002023053112364820230531123707
20230704225151KKKKKKKKK         9C28F1EB01341234567890123   0000472MO000000000.00000N82
20230703215437KKKKKKKKK         992CEDE00134112233445       0000022MO000000000.00000NSL
20230704111018KKKKKKKKK         A4C0B8000127987654321       0000532MO000000000.00000NSL
```

And I need to remove the 11th and 12th characters on the second column if they both match 3 and 4 respectively.

The best I could came up with is this:

sed -E 's/^([^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+)([^[:blank:]]{10})(34)([^[:blank:]]+)[[:blank:]]+/\1\2\4 /'  file

```
HEADER2023053112460600000004000000000.000002023053112364820230531123707
20230704225151KKKKKKKKK         9C28F1EB011234567890123 0000472MO000000000.00000N82
20230703215437KKKKKKKKK         992CEDE001112233445 0000022MO000000000.00000NSL
20230704111018KKKKKKKKK         A4C0B8000127987654321       0000532MO000000000.00000NSL
```

Which **almost** gets the desired result. Problem is the spacing between the third and fourth column: the lines that got replaced messed with the original number of spaces and I need it to be the exact same thing.

Any help would be most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion :

```
sed -e '1b; s/^\(\S\+\s\+\w\{10\}\)34\(\w\+\)/\1\2  /' INPUTFILE
```

Based on the input sample your provided, the output is:

```
HEADER2023053112460600000004000000000.000002023053112364820230531123707
20230704225151KKKKKKKKK         9C28F1EB011234567890123     0000472MO000000000.00000N82
20230703215437KKKKKKKKK         992CEDE001112233445         0000022MO000000000.00000NSL
20230704111018KKKKKKKKK         A4C0B8000127987654321       0000532MO000000000.00000NSL
```

Hope that helps.